# Where is jenkinsfile downloaded when job fetches pipeline script from SCM

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I created a Jenkinsfile and pushed it to master branch.
In Jenkins pipeline job, I selected `Pipeline Script from SCM` and filled all other details.

When I build this job, it runs properly as expected.

Console log says 'Obtained Jenkinsfile from git `<repo url>`'.

I am using windows. Jenkins has a folder .jenkins in `C:\Users\<Username>`.
I looked in workspace folder which is empty until Jenkinsfile started downloading the repo.

Where is Jenkins storing the Jenkinsfile it downloaded in the very first step?

Comment: What's the actual problem?  _Why_ do you need to see it? Could imagine that it only stored in memory.

Comment: I am interested in knowing how Jenkinsfile is fetched from repository? 
I have a legacy project which occupies 1.6GB. I dont want to fetch the entire repository to read Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0):

The output on the console log should show the directory where the Jenkinsfile was checked out. It is usually named somthing similar to what the workspace is called, but with an @script or something on the end.